# Compare User AD and CSV file column Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm not really good in Powershell, I try to write a script to compare a column "User" in a CSV with my all user AD.

I need to get all users in the CSV where not in our AD.

Here what I have wrote :

```
$csvfile = Import-CSV USERAccountstocompare.csv
$alladusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select sAMAccountName

foreach($user in $alladusers){
$userAD = $alladusers.SamAccountName

foreach($usercsv in $csvfile){

if ($usercsv | where {$_.user -ne "$userAD"}){ write "$usercsv"}

else{}
}
}
```

When I put a write $usercsv before the if command; I get the good user
but after the if, it write all user with @{User= before, like "@{User=username}" so the comparison not working.

Comment: you need to either expand the object property OR to use dot notation to get the value in the object property.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a foreach loop for this; just filter with `Where-Object`.

Assuming the `User` column in the CSV contains SamAccountNames:

```
$csvUsers   = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\USERAccountstocompare.csv'
$allADUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMAccountName
$notADUsers = $csvUsers | Where-Object { $allADUsers -notcontains $_.User }

# output on screen
$notADUsers | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to new CSV file
$notADUsers | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\UsersNOTinAD.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

`$alladusers = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select sAMAccountName` is not a very good idea if the Domain you are working on is big. Using `Where-Object` is also not a very good idea for filtering big objects, there was a really cool article in powershell.org where Dave Wyatt and Don Jones explained the different ways of filtering an object and their efficiency, sadly it was removed for some reason.

I would do something like this, assuming your Csv has a column 'User' for each user:

```
$result=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
#result array will be only the user that do not exist in AD

$csvfile = Import-CSV USERAccountstocompare.csv

foreach($line in $csvfile.User)
{
    $filter="(|(Name=$line)(samAccountName=$line))"
    $adusr=Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter $filter

    if(!$adusr)
    {
        $result.add($line) > $null
    }
}
```

If instead, you wanna have a list of the users that are on the Csv and on AD and those that are only in the Csv you could do something like this:

```
$result=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
#result array will be only the user that do not exist in AD

$csvfile = Import-CSV USERAccountstocompare.csv

foreach($line in $csvfile.User)
{
    $filter="(|(Name=$line)(samAccountName=$line))"
    $adusr=Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter $filter

    if(!$adusr)
    {
        $result.add(
            [pscustomobject]@{
                'Not In AD'=$line
        }) > $null
    }
    else
    {
        $result.add(
            [pscustomobject]@{
                'In AD and Csv'=$line
        }) > $null
    }
}
```